# Could not get the action in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added this function in my functions.php, so i have issues with the post action. how can i redirect the subscribers to home page?

```
function themeblvd_redirect_admin(){
  if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ){
    wp_redirect( site_url() );
    exit;   
  }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'themeblvd_redirect_admin' );
```

i have issues with this function, it is working fine, but i could not get the action to other plugins, how can i redirect the subscribers? any other methode?

Comment: If you agree with plugins! then use [WordPress Login Redirect](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-login-redirect/) plugin .

Comment: What does this mean: *but i could not get the action to other plugins* ?

Comment: wordpress ajax conflict with this function, when i put this function my I can not up vote, it will load the whole home page, then i removed this function now it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

First to correct your code,  instead of using current user capabilities i would suggest getting the role of the current user and do the redirection as below:

```
function themeblvd_redirect_admin(){
global $current_user, $wpdb;
$role = $wpdb->prefix . 'capabilities';
$current_user->role = array_keys($current_user->$role);
$role = $current_user->role[0];
if ($role=="subscriber"){
  wp_redirect( site_url() );
    exit;   
  }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'themeblvd_redirect_admin' );
```

Second not sure where you want this redirection. if you put it in functions then it will be applicable globally so use some role manager plugin to do this.......